# Coffeescript whitespace between function name and left parenthese

Tags: syntax, coffeescript

What sense does the whitespace between a function name and the left parenthese make?

```coffeescript
foo=(x,y)->x*y
foo(1,2) # ok
foo (1,2) # not ok
```

The last line above gives an `error: unexpected ,` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Coffeescript you can invoke a function which takes arguments with or without parenthesis:

```
foo(1,2)
foo 1, 2
```

If you have a space, then it well interpret whatever follows on the same line as the arguments. Let's take the example of another function `bar` which only takes one argument:

```
bar = (x) -> x * x
```

You could call this with a space before the parenthesis:

```
bar (2)
# ---> 4
```

This is because the parenthesis in Coffeescript (or Javascript) can be used to wrap an expression as well as invoke a function. Common examples are in `if` statements or for complex conditional / mathematical expressions. In the case of `bar (2)`, the contents of the expression are evaluated simply to 2 (same as if you typed `2` into a coffee CLI). This is then passed to `bar` as if you called `bar 2`.

For your function `foo` which takes two arguments, it evaluates `(1,2)` as an expression. But `,` is not a valid operator so it throws an error. Same as if you typed `1,2` into a coffee CLI.

Comment: Thanks. this make me switch back to plain JavaScript again ;-b